# Java - Calculator in JFrame - Division doesn't work?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, calculator, division

I've made a calculator with java using JFrame, and everything works except the division.
Here is the bit of code which calculates the answer and displays it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(resultl.getText());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(resultl.getText());
            if (oper.equals("+")) {
                answer = num1 + num2;
                resultm.setText("" + answer);
                resultl.setText("");
                resultr.setText("");
                oper = "";
                currentNuml = "";
                currentNumr = "";
            } else if (oper.equals("-")) {
                answer = num1 - num2;
                resultm.setText("" + answer);
                resultl.setText("");
                resultr.setText("");
                oper = "";
                currentNuml = "";
                currentNumr = "";   
            } else if (oper.equals("*")) {
                answer = num1 * num2;
                resultm.setText("" + answer);
                resultl.setText("");
                resultr.setText("");
                oper = "";
                currentNuml = "";
                currentNumr = "";
            } else if (oper.equals("/")) {
                answer = num1 / num2;
                resultm.setText("" + answer);
                resultl.setText("");
                resultr.setText("");
                oper = "";
                currentNuml = "";
                currentNumr = "";
            }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                resultl.setText("Unexpected Error, try again.");
        }
    }
```

I pasted in the whole thing that generates the answer for comparison, but really the division bit is the problem. If I do anything to do with division it ALWAYS just says the answer is 1.0
 - Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading from the same `JTextField` for `num2` so the values will be the same. Any `double` divided by itself will yield `1.0`.

```
num2 = Double.parseDouble(resultl.getText());
```

You probably want:

```
num2 = Double.parseDouble(result2.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks, just an annoying typo as usual :(

Answer (score 4):

```
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(resultl.getText());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(resultl.getText());
```

num1 and num2 are the same value => division delivers 1.0